# converting the hyperlinks in a string to text using php

Tags: php, regex, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to remove the hyper link from a string, i am displaying the string in a text box, currently it's displaying the hyper link in the text box, but while displaying i would like to remove the hyper link from the string.

The following is the string:

```
<?php
$string='new text <a href="/users/php">#php</a>';
echo $this->form->textarea('message', array('value'=>$string)));
 ?>
```

Here i want to remove the link and need to display the string as 'new text #php'

Comment: Use [strip_tags()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php

$string = 'new text <a href="/users/php">#php</a>';

echo $this->form->textarea('message', array('value'=> strip_tags($string)));

?>
```

learn more at [php strip_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$newstr = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@', '<a href="$1" >$1</a>', $str);
```

Comment: @divyaamitpatel What's this comment hum... means?

Comment: i can't display this string in textbox, because #php is displaying as a link in the textbox

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
$pattern = "~^(.*)<a[^>]*>([^<]*)~";
$replacement = "$1$2";
$string = 'new text <a href="/users/php">#php</a>';
$new_string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
echo $new_string; //=> new text #php
?>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pQ9aP5)